Why is the definition of $\pi$ as integral by Weierstrass "inverted"?
Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Definition I stumpled upon the following definition as an integral, presumably given by Weierstrass:
$$
\pi = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
However I don't understand, why one would use such a definition. Starting from the equation for a circle with radius one $x^2+y^2=1$ we get $y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and a much more natural definition of $\pi$ would be two times the area under this curve like
$$
\pi = 2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx
$$
Why did Weierstrass instead choose to give an "inverted" definition?
Update: I noted that also the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_constant#Forms is usually also defined in "inverted" form like
$$
\varpi = \int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}
$$
instead of the more natural definition as area under the curve defined by $x^4 + y^4 = 1$ like
$$
\varpi = 2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt[4]{1-x^4}\,dx
$$

It's hidden in the notes, but Wikipedia says that Gauss' definition was actually $\pi=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{x^2+1},dx$.

your integral defines $\pi$ as an area. The given integral defines $\pi$ more traditionally as (half) the circumference

Have you looked at the indefinite integral of both expressions? Weirstrauss's choice cleanly evaluates to exactly arcsine(x), whereas your area-under-the-curve choice has that plus an additional root-times-polynomial term.  Granted, that term is odd and cancels itself out over the (-1,1) limits, but that additional term means that the "behind the scenes" work of computing that integral is more difficult.

@SassatelliGiulio: You mean Weierstraß, not Gauß, right? As per the note I quote in my answer.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Yes.

I also cannot read Weierstraß' mind, but I can read the note in the Wikipedia article which says that Weierstraß actually proposed neither of the integrals you and the other answers discuss as a definition, but rather
$$\pi := \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
And I can read the free preview of the reference for that, namely, p. 148 of Remmert's article on $\pi$ in Ebbinghaus et al.'s Numbers book. It explains that Weierstraß' starting point, unsurprisingly for a complex analyst, would have been
$$\int_{S^1} \frac{dz}{z} =2\pi i$$
i.e. more thinking of the circumference of the unit circle $S^1$. And further, that Weierstraß used the parametrization $z(\lambda) = \frac{1+i\lambda}{1-i\lambda}$, $-\infty <\lambda <\infty$ for the unit circle (which, by the way, is the special case for Hilbert 90 everyone should have seen once), which makes
$$\int_{S^1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2i \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
One can of course further note that by symmetry
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
and by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
so that alternatively, if we dislike improper integrals, we can set
$$\pi := 4 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
In chapter 6 §1 no. 3 of Remmert's book Theory of Complex Functions (p. 174/175 here), he expands this a little and quotes from Weierstraß that all he needs to build function theory from the above is this integral gives a finite, nonzero number.
Note that this definition does not even involve roots (which, as one learns in higher math, are more intricate than they seem in high school) -- in fact, the definition
$$\pi := 4 \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
only involves a finite integral with easiest bounds over a rational function with easiest coefficients. It would be hard to find a more "rational"/"algebraic" definition for the (very irrational and un-algebraic) number $\pi$.
The exact Weierstraß reference is "Darstellung einer analytischen Function einer complexen Veränderlichen, deren absoluter Betrag zwischen zwei gegebenen Grenzen liegt", written in 1841, but published only in 1894 in the collected Mathematische Werke. That is available online at  https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139567787.003 but you need institutional access for this.
Edit: Luckily, user M. Lonardi found this free version of Weierstraß' paper: https://archive.org/details/mathematischewer01weieuoft/page/52/mode/2up?view=theater in their post here.

So basically Weierstrass prefers to define $\pi$ via the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Rotational_symmetry ?

I don't know what you are trying to say with that link but I am very sure that Weierstraß did not think of anything related to probability distributions. As I try to explain in my answer, he just uses a very ingenious but basic parametrization of the circumference of a circle. That is what that integral is, and it avoids that ugly square root in both of yours.

When you say Hilbert 90, do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90 ?

@asmaier: Yes. -

I cannot read Weierstrass's mind, but it entirely possible that he was not using the area of a circle as the starting point. He may have been deriving his result from the properties of the inverse sine function.
We can convert the area of the unit circle to the Weierstrass form using integration by parts. To set this up, first render
$\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=[x\sqrt{1-x^2}]|_{-1}^{+1}-\int_{-1}^{+1}x d(\sqrt{1-x^2}).$
Then the boundary term is zero and the derivative of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is $-x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so:
$\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^{+1}\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_{-1}^{+1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$
$\therefore\color{blue}{2\int_{-1}^{+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^{+1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.}$
